# drop-down (select) text not refreshing on javascript update

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple drop-down menu...

```
Select your favorite fruit:
<select name="fruit" id="fruit">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option SELECTED>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

I have tried doing this...

```
document.getElementById("fruit").value = "";
```

...which changes the selection to the first option

I have also tried doing this...

```
document.getElementById("fruit").length=0;
```

...which deletes all the options.

I have also tried doing this...

```
document.getElementById("fruit").innerHTML="<option value=''>NEW</option>";
```

...which replaces the options with a new one.

All of those work as expected when not in my actual code. The problem is when I try and include it in a page inside my WordPress plugin.

What happens is... the value changes and is evident if I click on it after ...but... the display text in the drop-down stays as the original text "Orange" (even if that text doesn't actually exist in the drop-down anymore) until I actually change to a new selection.

I have tried searching for any relevant content that might affect it but I can't see anything. Between WordPress itself, the theme, the plugin, etc., there is just too much code to display here. I am simply hoping someone has seen the issue before and can point me in the right direction and let me know what to look for.

Comment: um, your code should be throwing an error since the id is fruit_1, not fruit

Comment: Sorry... My bad... fruit_1 was not actually there. The _1 was left over from copying from my original code... I updated the original post.

Comment: You may want to provide reproducible test case for people to see and help.

Comment: As I mentioned, it works when I have the code by itself and there is so much other code that I can not determine what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact your `id='fruit_1'` but you are using `fruit` which is the `name` and not the `id` of the select element.

Use `document.getElementById("fruit_1")` instead of `document.getElementById("fruit")`. That should work.

Comment: Sorry... My bad... fruit_1 was not actually there. The _1 was left over from copying from my original code... I updated the original post.